# FCM push notification via AlamoFire - URLSessionTask failed with error: Could not connect to the server

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, alamofire

I'm trying to implement FCM to send a push notification (using the legacy api), but am unable to do so.

I have verified that my server key (taken from Firebase console) and device token are accurate, and I have successfully sent a push note to my device via Postman.

However, I am unable to do so via code. I am calling the below code from my simulator and "attempting" to send a push note to my physical device.

```
let urlString: String = "https://fcm/googleapis.com/fcm/send"
let key = "key=[my server key]"

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": key
]

let notificationParameters: Parameters = [
    "to": "[my push token of physical device]",
    "notification": [
        "title": "My title",
        "body": "My body"
    ]
]

print("1")
AF.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: 
notificationParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: 
headers).responseJSON { response in
    print("3")
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        printSuccess("Successfully sent notification")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Failed to send notification: \(error)")
        print(error.errorDescription)
        print(error.failureReason)
    }
    print("4")
}
print("2")
```

Here's the log:

```
1
2
2022-03-31 15:23:24.725607-0500 Wurtle with Friends[22207:12775410] 
[connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR 
[61: Connection refused]
2022-03-31 15:23:24.727572-0500 Wurtle with Friends[22207:12775410] 
Connection 3: received failure notification
2022-03-31 15:23:24.727789-0500 Wurtle with Friends[22207:12775410] 
Connection 3: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2022-03-31 15:23:24.728130-0500 Wurtle with Friends[22207:12775410] 
Connection 3: encountered error(1:61)
2022-03-31 15:23:24.729779-0500 Wurtle with Friends[22207:12775409] 
[boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed 
to log metrics
2022-03-31 15:23:24.731134-0500 Wurtle with Friends[22207:12775410] 
Task <B52206D8-E22D-4D8F-B3F5-815692558860>.<1> HTTP load failed, 
0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2022-03-31 15:23:24.736922-0500 Wurtle with Friends[22207:12775410] 
Task <B52206D8-E22D-4D8F-B3F5-815692558860>.<1> finished with error 
[-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect 
to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x60000279c300 {Error 
Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo=
{_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: 
en1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, 
_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <B52206D8-
E22D-4D8F-B3F5-815692558860>.<1>, 
_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <B52206D8-E22D-4D8F-B3F5-815692558860>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://fcm/googleapis.com/fcm/send, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://fcm/googleapis.com/fcm/send, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
3
Failed to send notification: sessionTaskFailed(error: Error 
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the 
server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x60000279c300 {Error 
Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo=
{_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: 
en1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, 
_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <B52206D8-
E22D-4D8F-B3F5-815692558860>.<1>, 
_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <B52206D8-E22D-4D8F-B3F5-815692558860>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://fcm/googleapis.com/fcm/send, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://fcm/googleapis.com/fcm/send, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1})
Optional("URLSessionTask failed with error: Could not connect to 
the server.")
4
```

This is my first time implementing FCM and I've been stuck on it for a while now, so any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why you want trigger FCM in iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I do not recommend sending an FCM request straight from the app, it appears you have a typo in your server URL address.

Just change it to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Comment: Oh my gosh..................you're right. Wow this whole time I thought it was something I wasn't understanding. I spent two days researching prior to this. Makes me question if I even like coding after all lol.

Answer (score 0):

you must get the FCM token and refresh token as the firebase console said in the Appdelegate file:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

you shouldn't send push from the iOS app, this is not secure because of the server key and etc, and also you must add the cloud message certificate and message key as firebase requested.
and also you must have destination fcm token (per device).
Push Notification Sender must be your Backend that have all device FCM Tokens.

you must send FCM Token that you get in Appdelegate per ["user" , "device"] to backend and your backend must save it for user device.

FCM Token is a map key foreach device APNS token.

Comment: Thanks for your response Maziar. I am already getting the updated FCM token in the App Delegate; the code I posted has the token manually typed in for simplicity. I have tried it both ways and have verified the token is updated and correct but it still logs the same errors. I have also done all of the other things you mentioned (except for actually sending the push notification from the backend). The push notification sends correctly as a test message from the Firebase console, as well as from Postman.

Comment: Do you think it is because I am trying to send a push notification from my simulator to a physical device? I know simulators can't receive push notifications, but can they at least send them out to a physical device? That is what I am doing here. My simulator is sending the push notification to the supplied device token (which is the device token of my physical device, which is registered for push notifications).

Comment: Also, you mention that you shouldn't send push notification from the iOS app due to the server key not being secure. So does this mean I have to trigger my backend to trigger FCM to trigger APNs just to send a push notification? Wouldn't that be very redundant?....

Comment: @Eric [my push token of physical device] is the same device you are in, when you send a push to another device you must have a destination token, how do get the destination token? when you can send a push from the client, every body can send it, so I can send a push to your clients(even with postman), FCM is a middle ware to unify send push notification both platform (android and ios, web) and your backend don't want implement both push API and should just implement FCM. this is not redundant.

Comment: @Eric for example if I send a request to backend, the backend knows which user(users) must get a push notification and the client doesn't know about other user tokens, even a user maybe have multiple device, and all devices must get a push.

Comment: The push token is for my physical device which I am sending the notification to. I am retrieving the push token from my backend database prior to sending the notification. I am running the above code in my simulator to send a push notification to my physical device.

Comment: @Eric to me this solution is incorrect because of the security issue, I can get your curl request (from client) and send everything I want to your clients. by the way add this to info.plist <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
maybe helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243587/discussion-between-eric-and-maziar-saadatfar).